# "Non-exhaustive patterns" error when summing a list of lists

Tags: list, haskell

All I'm trying to do is sum a list of lists. Example of what I want to do:

**Input**: `[[1,2,3],[2,5],[6,7]]`

**Output**: `[6,7,13]`

The amount of lists inside the outer list can vary, and the amount of integers in each inner list can vary. I've tried a multitude of things, and this is the last one I tried but it doesn't work:

```
sumSubsets [[x]] = map sum [[x]]
```

Also, I wanted a base case of sumSubsets `[] = [[]]` but that causes errors as well. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `map sum` should be enough...

Comment: A heads-up: I have changed the title to better reflect the underlying problem, and to mention the error which (I presume) you saw. (In such cases, it is always a good idea to quote the errors you get.)

Answer (score 2):

You could use

```
sumSubsets x = map sum x
```

or even

```
sumSubsets = map sum
```

Your previous code,

```
sumSubsets [[x]] = map sum [[x]]
```

First performs a *pattern match* using `[[x]]` which matches a list containing a single element, which is itself a list containing a single element. Therefore it would work correctly on `[[3]]`

```
>> sumSubsets [[3]]
[3]
```

but not on `[[1,2,3]]` or `[[1],[2]]`.

Comment: Woooow, ok, I can't believe the square brackets were what was messing it up. I knew the concept was right. Ok. Thank you.

Question though, why is it that just x works, but [x] or [[x]] doesn't?

Comment: `[[x]]` is a pattern for a list containing exactly one list, just as `[x]` is a list with exactly one element. Just `x` is any input of any shape

Comment: Another question. Would the code need to change at all to have output of [[6],[7],[13]] instead of [6,7,13]?

Comment: @MandyLB You would have to compose `sum` with a function that makes a single element list. It would become `map ((\x -> [x]) . sum)`, or simply `map ((:[]) . sum)`. (In any case, do keep in mind that `6` and `[6]` are very different things indeed.)

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem stems primarily from mixing up types and values, which can happen easily to the beginner, in particular on lists. The whole confusion probably comes from the fact that in Haskell, `[]` is used as a data constructor as well as a type constructor.

For example, `[Int]` means "a list of Ints" (a type), but `[1]` means "the list that contains one element, namely the number 1" (a value -- meaning, the whole list is the value). Both things together:

```
xs :: [Int]
xs = [1]
```

When you write polymorphic functions, you abstract from something like the `Int`. For example, if you want to get the first element of a list, you can define a function that does that for any kind of list -- may they be lists of integers or lists of characters or even lists of lists:

```
firstElement :: [a] -> a
firstElement (x:xs) = x
```

`[a]` means "a list with elements of type a" (a type), and the `a` alone means "something of type a". `firstElement` is a function from a list with elements of type a to something of type a. `a` is a type variable. Since you're not saying what `a` should be, the function works for all kinds of lists:

```
*Main> firstElement [1,2,3]
1

*Main> firstElement ['a','b']
'a'

*Main> firstElement [[1,2],[3,4]]
[1,2]
```

When you wrote `[[x]]` you were perhaps thinking of the type of the first argument of the function, which would be a list of lists of elements of some type x (`x` is a type variable). You can still use that, but you have to put it into the type signature of your function (the line that contains the double colon):

```
sumSubsets :: Num a => [[a]] -> [a]
sumSubsets xs = map sum xs
```

I've used `a` here instead of `x`, since it's more commonly done, but you could use `x`, too. Unfortunately, the whole thing gets a bit complicated with the `Num a` which describes additional requirements on the type `a` (that it belongs to the numbers, since for other things, `sum` is not defined). To simplify matters, you could write:

```
sumSubsetsInts :: [[Int]] -> [Int]
sumSubsetsInts xs = map sum xs
```